# Определение мата в шахматах?

Tags: алгоритм, шахматы

Подскажите пож как можно определить мат в шахматах? А то не могу придумать как это запрограммировать.
Дошел до того, что могу определять какие клетки под ударом, чтоб король туда не мог ходить.
Могу сделать, чтоб каждый раз проверяло не находится ли король под ударом... Это все можно, но вопрос и проблема в том, что если например король под ударом и все позиции куда он может походить тоже под ударом..
Остается такая штука как.. Противник жертвует фигурой прикрывая короля и после этого у короля например открывается свободная клетка для хода...

В общем, подскажите как кто видит как можно организовать мат для противника? Игра друг против друга, без "ИИ".

Comment: IMHO мат надо определять при рассмотрении хода, которым объявляется шах в процессе поиска лучшего хода (оценки позиции для каждого варианта хода).

Что- то слишком заумно вы сказали, гррр, что за фигня - не могу ни комментировать ни отвечать... :(

Comment: Если попросту, то смотрите. 

--

В процессе поиска хорошего хода Вы перебираете возможные ходы каждой фигуры (например белых). Для каждой такой попытки вызываете 

1) функцию, которая определяет допустим ли в принципе такой ход;

2) функцию, которая определяет поставлен ли шах (с проверкой мата);

3) функцию, которая определяет поставлен ли пат;

4) функцию вычисляющую оценку (в виде числа) позиции.

Выбираете несколько лучших по (4) ходов. Моделируете для каждого из них ответ черных (аналогичным образом). Повторяете несколько раз. 

Берете лучший начальный ход (белых). 

--

Так ?

Comment: Нет. Можно намного проще.

Это вообще не понимаю к чему..
............................
4) функцию вычисляющую оценку (в виде числа) позиции.

Выбираете несколько лучших по (4) ходов. Моделируете для каждого из них ответ черных (аналогичным образом). Повторяете несколько раз.

Берете лучший начальный ход (белых).
........................................
Это что-то на подобие ИИ.

Comment: @JDev, видимо я Вас неправильно понял. Вы не в шахматы играете, а просто двигаете фигурки. 

Да ?

Comment: авп, в вопросе не говорится про ИИ, там ПвП... ну и, например, в твоей последовательности можно упустить 4 пункт, если соблюдается 1

Comment: @Gorets, что такое **ПвП...** не понимаю. 

В моей последовательности если 1) **не выполняется**, то все остальные пункты для данной попытки хода **не рассматриваются**. Переходим к следующей попытке хода.

Если **выполняется 2) с результатом МАТ**, то остальные тоже не рассматриваются, т.к. цель достигнута.

IMHO очевидно.

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо, завтра покумекаю, а то что-то я сильно перегрелся сегодня.
Вот.. Просто дело в том, что у меня граф интерфейс и я делаю, чтоб все возможные ходы подсвечивались, возможный удар подсвечивался.. Вот.. Сейчас начал парится с тем, чтоб при попытке короля походить, чтоб он сначала проверял не под ударом ли то поле..
В принципе ничего сложного, но запутался уже..
Каждый раз какая-то проверка, и нужно всю доску осмотреть, и хочется чтоб поменьше кода.. :(

Answer (score 5):

Когда от делать нечего писал у меня было так: одна функция возвращает все возможные ходы фигуры, другая функция проверяет под шахом ли король определенной стороны.
Если наступил шах черным например, то перебираем все возможные ходы всех черных фигур. Если у всех ходов черный король под шахом, то это мат.
P.S. отсутствие ходов, когда король под шахом это тоже мат.

Comment: перебирать все - это долго =) мы тут размышлять можем долго, если кому-то интересно можно почитать как работает рыбка или схожие программы...

Comment: Особенно если перебирать на калькуляторе Электроника МК52.  
Мат это отсутствие ходов, способных исправить ситуацию шаха. Кроме полного перебора всех ходов всех фигур корректно работающих алгоритмов не существует.

Comment: имхо, полный перебор - это крайность, защиты от него тоже не существует, таких способом можно взломать любой сейф и расшифровать любой шифр, пароль и тд... если у тебя времени много...

Comment: @gorets, это не крайность... Это здравый смысл.   
Я погорячился, что других алгоритмов не существует, но гораздо удобнее сделать перебор, чем писать алгоритмы для следующих действий:  
1. Снять с доски фигуру (ы), которые атакуют короля.  
2. Переместить короля.  
3. Поставить другую фигуру на линию атаки.  
4. Проверить, что сделав вышеуказанные действия не будет ситуации шаха.

Comment: P.S. Хотя нет. Я не погорячился. Полный перебор это оптимальный вариант. Когда алгоритм будет проверять пункт 3 ему придется сделать полный перебор, то есть пункты 1 и 2 излишни.

Comment: 3.Поставить другую фигуру на линию атаки. -вооотттт, Спасибо, за отличную подсказку, будет достаточно проверки, может ли кто-то атаковать эту фигуру или стать на линию огня...

Comment: ты сам себя запутал, при правильно построенном алгоритме для игры - человек-человек, надо проверить всего пару условий для определения мата

Comment: Дык, вот, нужно сначала обдумать эту условия, а потом их программировать...

Comment: @jdev делай полный перебор и не мучайся :) чем проще алгоритм, тем лучше. Никакие сэкономленные 0.0001 мс не оправдают нецелесообразно сложного алгоритма :)

Comment: ReinRaus - так и сделаю, я не гонюсь за экономией, в наше времмя этого не видно, сейчас задумался как свое приложение чуток пересобрать.. так как локальная игра, было все хорошо, сделал сетевую, получилась немного каша...

Comment: @JDev,

    3.Поставить другую фигуру на линию атаки. -вооотттт, Спасибо, за отличную подсказку, будет достаточно проверки, может ли кто-то атаковать эту фигуру или стать на линию огня...

Только не забывайте, что переместившаяся на линию атаки фигура может открыть новую атаку на короля.  Т.е. при выборе допустимого хода **любой** фигуры необходима проверка - не попадает ли свой король под шах в результате этого хода. Иначе такой ход невозможен.

--

К вопосу о полном переборе для каждого полухода. Эффективность зависит от структуры данных, описывающих текущую позицию.

Comment: @ReinRaus то есть правильный алгоритм экономит какие-то 0.00001с? ну-ну

Comment: а как все это обдумать в коде. :):) Ну ничего прорвемся, главное чистая голова. :) Пользуюсь АррейЛистами, мне они наиболее подходят..

Answer (score 3):

При оценке позиции следует знать последний ход — на случай взятия на проходе:

Можно предложить очевидный линейный алгоритм.

1. Атаковано ли поле с королём? Если нет, то не мат.
2. Атакованы ли соседние с королём и свободные от его фигур поля? Если нет, то не мат.
3. Сколько фигур атакуют короля? Если две, то мат.
4. Можно ли съесть атакующую фигуру? Если да, то не мат.
5. Атакует конь? Если да, то мат.
6. Атакующая фигура на соседнем поле? Если да, то мат.
7. Можно ли перекрыть линию атаки? Если да, то не мат. Иначе - мат.

Comment: "Сколько фигур атакуют короля" - неверно, есть двойной шах.

Comment: @Зонтик После двух первых вопросов мы знаем,  что король под шахом и отступлений нет. Если шах двойной (от двойного шаха фигурами защититься невозможно), то с учётом предыдущей информации имеем мат на доске

Comment: А, понятно. Прошу прощение, ошибся :)

Answer (score 0):

> Могу сделать, чтоб каждый раз
> проверяло не находится ли король под
> ударом... Это все можно, но вопрос и
> проблема в том, что если например
> **король под ударом и все позиции куда
> он может походить тоже под ударом**..
> Остается такая штука как.. Противник
> жертвует фигурой прикрывая короля и
> после этого у короля например
> открывается свободная клетка для
> хода...

все правильно. просто надо постоянно проверять это условие.

**UPD1**

Понял проблему =) После этого условия надо еще проверить, возможность побить чем-то атакующею фигуру и возможность прикрыть себя

Тут много вариантов вырисовывается, надо смотреть на цвет клетки, смотреть кто есть на поле из фигур, кто может пойти на эту клетку. Кто атакует, с какой стороны и чем ее можно перекрыть..

Comment: Я же написал, что...
Остается такая штука как.. Противник жертвует фигурой прикрывая короля и после этого у короля например открывается свободная клетка для хода...

Comment: да, но ты перескакиваешь через 2а хода - а они могут все изменить..

Comment: Много полезной информации, нужно переварить...
Я почему еще задал вопрос.. Я не знаю как заканчивать игру..
Имеется ввиду например, проиграл такой-то игрок. А Такое нельзя писать исходя только из того, что король под ударом и ему некуда походить..

Comment: Значит так, добился пока этого, прошу поправить если что пропустил...

1. Если 2 шаха, то мат! Тоисть если король атакован двумя фигурами и ему некуда бежать.(сделал).
2. Если шах с одной фигуры и фигуру нельзя побить остается только подложить на пути атакующей фигуры другую фигуру. Правильно? 
3. Если фигуру нельзя побить и на пути нельзя ничего поставить и королю некуда бежать, то мат!

Еще варианты к определению мата в дополнение? Мыслей уже много прочитал, теперь стараюсь отобразить в коде, какие еще ситуации??

Еще бы придумать как "пат" определять... 

Всем спасибо!

Comment: Пат - не куда ходить и королю не мат. 

Первый твой пункт избыточный, а если 3 мата, 4? надо 1.

У тебя каждая фигура - это объект со свойствами?

Comment: Почему избыточный, я проверяю на больше чем один.
Если 1, то рассматриваю варианты 2 и 3 - интересуюсь все ли учел.
Да, каждая фиг объект со св. Но я работаю с обычной числовой матрицей. Ну.. чуток не получится сохранять какие либо свойства в фигуру...

Comment: @JDev, рассматривать 2 шаха **очевидный перебор**. 

IMHO мат надо определять при рассмотрении хода, которым объявляется шах в процессе поиска лучшего хода (оценки позиции для каждого варианта хода).

Пат надо определять в том же месте программы и в зависимости от общей оценки ситуации либо делать такой ход, либо избегать его.